# grep multiple statements from a file

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sh

I have a shell program that when runs writes the logs onto a log file.
Now at the end of the program , I would need to pick few of the lines (Start/end/no of records processed- its a line in log) and then push these to another program (java) . The java program needs to be called once and message lines need to be passed as a an array.

I have the java program ready but am not sure how to grep the lines from the log file and send it to java program in one single call.

There are many such programs which need to call this java program and send these lines and hence the grep content changes for each of the program

Example, one of the shell scripts logs below onto the log file.At the end of the shell script after the main processing is done

The program  should grep from the log file below 3 lines among the whole log file and send it to java program and exit successfully.

java -jar mylog.jar "JOB_1010" "logger1" "logger2" "logger3"

```
 [INFO] [MyScript.sh] --- Script Execution START
......
[INFO] [MyScript.sh] --- RECORDS PROC : 457
 .....
[INFO] [MyScript.sh] --- Script Execution END
```

How can i read these from log file and pass it as arguments to the java program

"JOB_1010" - Sample name of job
  "loggers 1-3"  - these are the grepped statements from log file

Note: These are sample log statements.

Comment: Does the first shell program (which writes the logs) call the Java program, or do you wait for the shell program to finish and then want to write a new script which reads the completed log file and starts the Java program?

Comment: You can start by giving an example of how the lines are stored in the log file and how you want the `java` program to take them as input

Comment: Add a sample log file in the question.

Comment: hi @ John  the first shell calls the java program at the end of the shell program and not a new script